# Testing SSL certificate on other IP address

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https

I'm about to buy an SSL certificate from GoDaddy for a site, let's say "example.com".

However I'm currently making design and performance updates in a non production VPS, using it's IP address. Let's say: 10.10.10.10

I would like to purchase the certificate to use it in example.com, but first I want to test https and everything in the non-production server.

This is probably a stupid question but I'm new to this area and I need to know if this will cause the certificate not to work on this other ip address(Before spending the money).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate doesn't change.  As long as you're only specifying the domain name, and not the IP address, in the certificate, it can be used on multiple machines.  You will have to adjust your test setup to point the domain to the test IP address.